# Computer doesn't sleep on disk decryption screen

Tags: suspend, encryption, overheating

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with LUKS full-disk encryption. When I enter the screen that asks me to enter the encryption key, the computer doesn't suspend until I've entered it. On two occasions, I have placed my laptop in my bag at this screen, causing it to overheat. Is there some setting, whether at the OS level or lower, that can have the computer sleep in this case?

Comment: What you appear to be trying to do makes no sense, at least to me. Why not enter the key and then it will suspend?